# Cannot ping between 2 Windows servers

Tags: windows, networking, ping

I have 2 physical Windows servers having 2 networks. One card is to access the internet and the other is for the internal network. For both servers, the internal card is assign to VLAN ID 100. Both internal card are set to Private network category.

Server A internal IP : 192.168.10.100 Server B internal IP : 192.168.10.200

After rebooting both servers, Server B cannot ping Server A using internal IP, but Server A can ping Server B.

After doing a ping from Server A to server B, now the server B can ping server A. I can't figure out why Server B cannot ping server A, until being pinged by Server A.

Thank you for any hint that can help to find the problem.

Comment: How are these two servers connected, is there a switch between them?

Comment: Probably, but I do not know, it is 2 servers inside the same data center.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After running "arp -a" on server B, I was able to ping server A. Then I reboot server B and I am still able to ping server A. It is like if the command "arp -a" remap correctly the IP with MAC address.

Answer (score 0):

First thing that I usually checking is the firewall. It might be that after restart it changes the location of that network and firewall may just block those pings. Also could you post full command how do you do ping?